# a topological property about property *

Tags: general-topology

Let us define property *:

> A topological space $‎(X,‎\tau‎  )‎$ has property *  ‎‎, if every open cover of ‎‎$X‎$‎ has a finite subfamily whose closures cover $X$.

Let $\mathbb{R}$ denote the set of real numbers with the standard (or usual) topology having as a basis the collection $(a, b)$ of all the bounded open intervals where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers and $a < b$.

Let $\mathbb{R}_l$ denote the set of real numbers with the lower limit topology having as a basis the collection $[a, b)$ of all the bounded closed-open intervals where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers and $a < b$.

1:  Do $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}_l$ have property *?

2:Let $X$ be a topological space with property * and $Y$ be a Hausdorff space.
Let $f:X ‎\longrightarrow ‎Y‎$ be a continuous function.  For every subset which has property * as $B$, does $ f‎^{-1}‎(B)$ have property *?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Also these are severeal questions in one.

Comment: This property is called feebly compact in the literature.

Answer (score 1):

As Henno Brandsma] answered:

> This property is called feebly compact in the literature.

1. The real line $\mathbb{R}$ is not compact, for the covering of $\mathbb{R}$ by open intervals
   $$ \mathcal{A}=\{(n,n+2):n \in \mathbb{Z} \} $$
   contains no finite subcollection that covers $\mathbb{R}$. 
   The $\mathbb{R}_l$ is not compact; because its basis is not a collection of compact sets 
   For example, the open covering of the interval (0,1]
   $$\mathcal{P}=\{(\frac{1}{n}, 1]:n \in \mathbb{Z} \} $$
   contains no finite subcollection cover (0,1]
2. Let $ f:X \longrightarrow Y $ be continuous; let X be compact. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a covering of the set $f(B)$ by open sets in $Y$
   $$f(B) \subset \bigcup_{\alpha \in I} A_i $$
   $$B \subset f^{-1}[f(B)] \subset f^{-1} (\bigcup_{\alpha \in I}A_i)= \bigcup_{\alpha \in I}f^{-1}(A_\alpha) $$
   Since $\mathcal{A}$ is in topological space, $ \{f^{-1}(A_\alpha):A_\alpha \in \mathcal{A} \}$ is in topological space.
   By hyppothesis, B is a compact set, there is a subsequence $\alpha_1, ...,\alpha_n$ such that $B \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n f^{-1}(A_{\alpha_i})$
   $$f^{-1}(A_{\alpha_1}),...,f^{-1}(A_{\alpha_n})$$ cover B. Then the sets $$A_{\alpha_1}, ..., A_{\alpha_n}$$ cover $f(B)$.